# Does vert.x zipkin integration provide support for sampling?

Tags: vert.x, zipkin, vertx4

**Use Case :**

Using vert.x application as an API gateway for all incoming traffic. Want to sample incoming requests through vert.x

Sampling option inside ZipkinTracingOptions is hard coded to Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE
I feel, we should provide the application an ability to supply Sampler from outside so that all sampling options supported by Brave can be used in ZipkinTracingOptions

**Does vert.x supports any other Sampling Option or does it intend to do that in future?**

Comment: Did you have a look at https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-zipkin/java/ ?

Comment: @tsegismont Yes,  I have read the documentation and code. I meant that Sampling option inside ZipkinTracingOptions is hard coded to Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE
I feel, we should provide the application an ability to supply Sampler from outside so that all sampling options supported by Brave can be used in ZipkinTracingOptions

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-tracing/issues/15